# Why can't we build virtualization that runs on several machines?

Tags: virtualization, xen

You're probably familiar with virtualization which takes a single host and is able to "emulate" many instances by sharing the resources among them all. You probably heard about [XEN](http://www.xen.org/).

Is it completely insane to imagine the "opposite" of XEN : a layer that would **abstract several hosts in a single running instance**? I believe this would allow building apps which wouldn't need to really care much about a "clustering" layer themselves.

I wonder what are the technical limits to this, because I'm pretty sure some people are already working on it somewhere :)

The goal is NOT to achieve any kind of failure recovery. I believe this can (and should?) be handled at a higher level. For example, if someone is able to run a MySQL server on a gigantic instance (made of say 50 hosts), then one can easily use MySQL's replication features to replicate the database over a similar virtual instance.

Comment: For what purpose? Increased processing power or failure recovery? I don't know much about it, but I've worked with a company which sells completely redundant hardware (Two of everything, running the exact same CPU instructions simultaneously). If one component fails, the next takes over with absolutely no service interruption.

Comment: I would probably focus on increasing power first. Failure recorvery can be achieved at a higher level, by replicating whatever services are required to another (similar) host.

Comment: checkout [Kerrighed](http://www.kerrighed.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Microsoft Azure is attempting to address this by allowing you to put applications "in the cloud" and not have to be as concerned with scalability up/down, redundancy, data storage, etc. But this is not accomplished at the hypervisor level.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/

Hardware-wise, there **are** some downsides to having everything be one big VM rather than many smaller ones. For one thing, software doesn't always understand how to handle all the resources. For example, some applications still can't handle multiple processor cores. I've seen informal benchmarks showing that IIS performs better spreading the same resources over multiple instances rather than one giant instance.

From a management perspective, it is probably better to have multiple VMs in certain cases. Imagine that a bad deployment corrupts a node. If that were your one and only (albeit giant) node, now your whole application is down.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you need to have different VMs for different purposes. But even with that, there are cases where someone would need a machine with 1TeraByte of RAM. It can't be achieved (or is probably extremely costly), while having 100 machines with 10GB is probably not that bad.

Comment: @Julien - absolutely. In some ways you are describing a supercomputer, which does exactly what you are asking with obvious benefits. But the major VM players with whom I am familiar (VMware, Citrix, Microsoft) seem to be much more focused on smaller VMs versus larger ones. For one thing, I think it is much harder to coordinate resources across physical boundaries (imagine coordinating RAM via a network connection). But that's just my semi-educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably talking about the concept [Single System Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image).

There used to be a Linux implementation, [openMosix](http://openmosix.sourceforge.net/) that since closed down. I don't know of any replacements. [openMosix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMosix) made it very easy to create and use SSI on a standard Linux kernel; too bad it got overtaken by events.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know enough about Xen to know if it is possible but with VMware you can create pools of resources which come from many physical hosts. Then you can assign the resources to your VMs. That could be many VMs or just one VM.
[Aggregation: Transform Isolated Resources into Shared Pools](http://www.vmware.com/technical-resources/advantages/aggregation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simulating a *single* core over *multiple physical cores* is very inefficient. You can do it, but it'll be slower than a cluster. Two physical cores can talk to each other in near-real-time, if they're on separate machines then you're doing something like say clocking down your motherboard speed by factors of 10 or more if these two physical cores (and RAM) are communicating even over a fibre optic network.

Dual cores can communicate faster than two distinct CPUs on the same motherboard, if they are on separate machines, thats slower again, if there are multiple machines, slower even again.

Basically you can, but there is net performance *loss* compared to the net performance *gain* you would be hoping to achieve.

Real life example, I had a bunch of VMs on a dual quad core server (~2.5Ghz/core) performing way, way below what they should have been. On closer inspection, it turned out that the hypervisor was emulating a single 3.5-4Ghz core when the load on an individual VM was more than 2.5Ghz -- after limiting each VM to 2.5Ghz performance went back to what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with saidimu, you are talking about the Single System Image concept.  In addition to the OpenMosix project, there have been several commercial implementations of the same idea (one contemporary example is ScaleMP).  It's not a new idea.

I just wanted to elaborate on some of the technical points of SSI.

Basically, the reason it's not done is because the performance is generally absolutely unpredictable or terrible.  There is a concept in computer systems known as [NUMA][3], which basically means that the cost of accessing different pieces of memory is not uniform.  This can apply to huge systems where CPUs may have some memory accesses routed around to different chips, or in cases where memory is accessed remotely over a network (such as in SSI).  Typically, the operating system will attempt to compensate for this by laying out programs and data in memory in such a way that a program can run as quickly as possible.  I.e., the code and data will all be placed in the same NUMA "region", and be scheduled on the closest possible CPU.

However, in cases where you are running big applications (attempting to use *all* the memory in your SSI), there is little the operating system can do to reduce the impact of remote memory fetches.  MySQL is not aware that accessing page 0x1f3c will cost 8 nanoseconds, while accessing page 0x7f46 will stall it for *hundreds of microseconds, possibly milliseconds while the memory is fetched over the network*.  This means that non-NUMA aware applications will run like crap (seriously, very bad) in this kind of environment.  As far as I know, most comtemporary SSI products rely on the fastest possible interconnects (such as Infiniband) between machines to achieve even a passable performance.

This is also why frameworks that expose the true cost of accessing data to the programmer (such as MPI: message passing interface) have achieved more traction than SSI or DSM (distributed shared memory) approaches.  In fact, there is basically no way for a programmer to optimize an application to run in an SSI environment, which just sucks.